# Excel VBA. I want to select a column and apply filter on that. Column need not to be at same place every time so need to select it by name string

Tags: vba, excel

Following code is generated by recording MACRO, need to select column and apply filter by column name.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("Logged On").AutoFilter Field:=4, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, "4/28/2016")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the columns' names and set the filter.

```
Option Explicit
'Applies a Filter to all Columns named "ColumnName" on the worksheet "ws" with a criteria "criteria"    
Sub ApplyFilterTOColumn(columnName As String, ws As Worksheet, criteria As String)

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A1"), ws.Range("A1").End(xlToRight))
For Each cell In rng

    If cell.Value = columnName Then

        cell.AutoFilter cell.Column, Criteria1:=criteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues

    End If

Next cell

End Sub


Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim columnName As String

columnName = "Example"
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
ApplyFilterToColumn columnName, ws, "b"

End Sub
```

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Comment: Thank You for help Mátray Márk . The solution worked for me.
I am facing trouble for setting right criteria for date now. I want to select a particular month of a year. Will greatly appreciate if you have any help to offer for this.